# How to read csv file content in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, html, csv, angular-directive

I want to read a csv file and get its content by using AngularJS and HTML5. I want to put the content of the csv file in $scope.

I have this code in my html

```
 <table align="center" >
            <tr class="borderless">
                <td>Choose .csv file</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="readCsvFile" id="readCsvFile" accept=".csv"> </td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Upload" ng-click="uploadCsvFile()"></td>
            </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

with a custom directive:

```
app.directive('fileReader', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fileReader:"="
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $(element).on('change', function(changeEvent) {
        var files = changeEvent.target.files;
        if (files.length) {
          var r = new FileReader();
          r.onload = function(e) {
              var contents = e.target.result;
              scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.fileReader = contents;
              });
          };

          r.readAsText(files[0]);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eeQbR65oE8iljm7ueGhX?p=preview

Comment: As a side note, you can use `r.readAsDataURL(files[0]);` so you can later output that file to an <img>

Comment: the result does not include the newline character ??, how do I know if a new line ??. Otherwise it works well

Comment: Can this be adapted to read csv files as JSON ? 
I don't see how FileReader can do this

Comment: @OsamaSalama sure you can: scope.fileReader = JSON.parse(contents)

Comment: @OsamaSalama if you are looking to parse .csv to JSON then I would recommend taking a look at the Papa Parse library.

Comment: Hi MajoB,is there a chance to do it without using directives?

Comment: @nlr_p Do you use angular?

Comment: @nlr_p Using directive is a good aproach for this, but you can let me know if manage it in a different way.